# Using import in babel standalone for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, babeljs

I'm trying to run React in Babel-standalone and use import from nearby files.
I prefer not using a bundler for this, nor to use solutions that aren't import/export.

Here is a concise sample of the problem:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.19.3/babel.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root-box"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">
      import { Something } from "./Something.js";
      ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root-box")).render(
        <Something />
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Something.js

```
export const Something = () => {
  return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

The resulting error is:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at Something.js:2:10)`
which means that babel has obtained the other file, but did not transpile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two issues here. Firstly you are not including Something.js in your script sources to be compiled by Babel. Secondly the UMD modules transform is not being applied, preventing the import from working correctly. Therefore, a working version of your code looks like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.19.3/babel.js"></script>
    <script data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" type="text/babel" data-presets="react" data-type="module" src="Something.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root-box"></div>
    <script data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" type="text/babel" data-presets="react" data-type="module">
      import { Something } from "./Something.js";
      ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root-box")).render(
        <Something />
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is working. 
Do you know where in the Babel standalone documentation this is noted? (found it in the general babel docs, but not the standalone)

Comment: @Eran how would one use imports from react?

Comment: @AngrySamurai react is already imported on the 3rd line, so use `React.useState`